# Invert negative values in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a list that contains negative values, to a list of non-negative values; inverting the negative ones. I have tried `abs` but it didn't work.

My input is

```
x = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10]
```

How can I make it into this format as I am trying calculate the area

```
x = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try a list comprehension:

```
x2 = [abs(k) for k in x]
```

Answer (score 5):

Your attempt didn't work because `abs()` takes an integer, not a list. To do this, you'll have to either loop through the list:

```
x = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10]
for i in range(len(x)):
     x[i] = abs(x[i])
```

Or you can use list comprehension, which is shorter:

```
x = [abs(i) for i in x]
```

Or simply use the built-in `map` function, which is even shorter :)

```
x = list(map(abs, x))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

The simple pythonic way is the list comprehension above but if you're using Numpy for anything else you could do:

```
x2 = numpy.abs(x)
```

with no need to convert or do any looping.

Comment: That's a bit too far, no need for numpy here.

Comment: I agree and I put caveats in my answer; however it's the shortest and simplest option from a syntax perspective and it seems the question is from a relatively inexperienced python-er, who has probably not heard of list comprehensions or map either.

Comment: And.. who probably never heard of numpy at all. Well, you actually have a have a good point though.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this answer (but to be fair I thought of this solution when I read the question as well) is that it returns a numpy array and not a list.  It's a small point, but at least something to point out.

Comment: In that case, numpy.abs(x).tolist()

Answer (score 1):

what you want is to use the absolute value (|x| = x if x > 0, |x| = -x if x < 0)

```
for index in range(len(x)):
    x[index] =  x[index] if x[index] > 0 else -x[index]
```

Comment: You don't have to do this, you can use `abs` instead. Python provided a built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a wrong answer to your question, but this is what I came here looking for. This is how to invert all the numbers in your list using [operator.neg](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.neg); i.e. also positives to negatives.

```
import operator
x = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10]
x = list(map(operator.neg, x))
```

It returns:

```
[-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Or you can do a list comprehension of course:

```
x = [-xi for xi in x]
```